# Limiting number of rows in a page

Tags: xsl-fo

I have a table with, suppose, 20 rows and i want the table to be displayed such that each page will have only 5 rows. So the 20 rows should be displayed in 4 pages.
I am using apache FOP to print the PDF.
Anyone can help me out in this?

Comment: Are you using XSL to build the FO? You do not have any information about what you have even tried. If you are using XSL, then match on the element that is the table and apply-templates for the rows using position() and mod() to collect them in groups of your desired number. Search the web for a FO example the colors every other row for inspiration.

Comment: @KevinBrown I am using Xsl to build FO. Could you pls elaborate with an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how is achieved this.

```
<xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="position() mod 4 = 0">
      <!-- Add table rows here with property break-after-->
      <fo:table-row break-after="page">
         <fo:table-cell>
            <xsl:text>Table content here</xsl:text>
         </fo:table-cell>
     </fo:table-row>
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise>
      <!-- Add table rows here without property break-after-->
      <fo:table-row>
         <fo:table-cell>
            <xsl:text>Table content here</xsl:text>
         </fo:table-cell>
     </fo:table-row>
   </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```